# How to control (only) Youtube Music with media keys

Tags: macos, keyboard, google-chrome, music, youtube

Is there a way to control only YouTube Music with media keys?

Currently, if I have YT Music playing in some window in the background and then open a YouTube video and want to pause the music - YouTube catches the media key.

I think it is configured to pass the media keys to the active/last active tab.

I rarely need to control YouTube with media keys so I would be fine with a setup that would work only with YT Music.

(I don't have Google Music Desktop app as that causes problems)

I also tried Google Chrome with disabled hardware media keys and the [streamkeys](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/streamkeys/ekpipjofdicppbepocohdlgenahaneen) extension which allows you to enable it for each site and define priority - next/previous track works but not play/pause. To be precise, pause works only when pressed within a second or two after play.